# Lua)) how to loop table of table and get a specific property?

Tags: lua, lua-table, pico-8

I am really newbie in lua. I have this lua code

```
local gun_info = {
   g_sword={rate=0.5;spd=0;dmg=1;ammo=1;};
   g_pistol={rate=0.5;spd=5;dmg=1;ammo=40;};
   g_knife={rate=0.8;spd=5;dmg=1;ammo=1;};
   g_shuriken={rate=0.3;spd=5;dmg=1;ammo=40;};
   g_bomb={rate=0.8;spd=5;dmg=1;ammo=20;};
};
```

I just want get values of every ammo. Other properties are no needed.

```
for k, v in pairs(gun_info) do
  print(k, v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5])
end
```

this prints out whole tables but I need just value of ammos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use comma between table variables rather than semicolon. Using semicolon is not syntactically wrong but optional in Lua. Semicolon is usually used to separate multiple statements written in single line.

You can directly access the variable `ammo` by indexing the key of the table

```
for k, v in pairs(gun_info) do
    print(k, v.ammo)
end
```

v.ammo and v[ammo] are not same in Lua.

Note: The order in which the elements appear in traversal will not be the same as you defined and can produce different order each time. This is due to the way tables are implemented in Lua.

Comment: Thanks. If I improve your answer, can I use v[1].ammo if I need first ammo?

Comment: No. In your case you need to know the key. table in lua is an associative array. v[1] will be a different table index. You can access the first ammo by gun_info.g_sword.ammo

Comment: So you mean if I need first ammo, I need loop gun_info.g_sword.ammo? not gun_info? Can't it be done more dynamically? because I think it is silly to loop five times if I need number of specific ammo

Comment: You no need to loop. If you know the keys you can directly access it. print(gun_info.g_sword.ammo)